# if statement display the error message more than once

Tags: checkout, magento-1.9, if

i have a check in my checkout to see if a product has the attribute direct delivery set to yes and if so it should display a message. However if there is more than one product in the basket with the attribute set to yes it displays the message more than once. How can i stop the message form displaying more than once?

This is the IF statement i have.

```
<?php $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        $cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
        foreach ($cartItems as $item)
        {
            $productId = $item->getProductId();
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
                   if($product->getData('direct_delivery_product')==1){?>

             <div class="direct_message">
             <?php echo 'You have direct delivery products in your shopping cart. This means it may take longer than the standard 2-5 working days to deliver.';?></div>

                <?php unset($_shippingRateGroups["freeshipping"]);

             }

                }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
<?php $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        $cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
        foreach ($cartItems as $item)
        {
            $productId = $item->getProductId();
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
                   if($product->getData('direct_delivery_product')==1){?>

             <div class="direct_message">
             <?php echo 'You have direct delivery products in your shopping cart. This means it may take longer than the standard 2-5 working days to deliver.';?></div>

                <?php unset($_shippingRateGroups["freeshipping"]);
                break;

             }

                }
?>
```

Have added a break.

Comment: thank you. i knew it was something simple. I tried to put a break in put i had it in the wrong place. Thank you

Comment: Please select this as the correct answer.

Comment: i tried but it has a timer on it so i had to wait for that to expire. Thank you again

Comment: oh ok..cheers :)